# How to convert AWS ClouldWatch Dashboard into CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a Cloudwatch dashboard via AWS Console. Now I would like to convert it to its Cloudformation template for future deployment.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Thanks for answer! It was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case there's not much to convert, because the dashboard definition in CloudFormation [`AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudwatch-dashboard.html) must appear, not defined in YAML or even in JSON, but represented as a literal *string representation of the JSON* (i.e. a literal JSON representation *embedded* in the CloudFormation template, not part of the CloudFormation template).You can see this in one of the official [CloudFormation templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudwatch.html#cloudwatch-sample-dashboard-basic):

```yaml
BasicDashboard:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
  Properties:
    DashboardName: Dashboard1
    DashboardBody: '{"widgets":[{"type":"metric","x":0,"y":0,"width":12,"height":6,"properties":{"metrics":[["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","InstanceId","i-012345"]],"period":300,"stat":"Average","region":"us-east-1","title":"EC2 Instance CPU"}},{"type":"text","x":0,"y":7,"width":3,"height":3,"properties":{"markdown":"Hello world"}}]}'
```

Thus you simply need to copy and paste the [JSON source code of your existing dashboard](https://repost.aws/questions/QUzarTQVN5TgqAVeXR6_h6Bg/cloudwatch-dashboard-source-json) into the CloudFormation template and add the minimal `AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard` and dashboard name boilerplate.

Tip: You can can paste the multiple lines of JSON as-is using a [YAML multiline](https://yaml-multiline.info/) string, with the following syntax:

```yaml
BasicDashboard:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
  Properties:
    DashboardName: Dashboard1
    DashboardBody: >-
      {
        "widgets": [
          {
            …
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) to generate CloudFormation template based on your existing dashboards.